# Save docx as pdf AppleScript MS Word script for use in Shortcuts.app on macOS

Tags: macos, pdf, ms-word, applescript, docx

I created a shortcut (for shortcuts.app) for automatic pdf document processing, but i need to convert some docx files to pdf first. I've made a loop (in shortcuts.app), that gets docx files as an input. I can insert AppleScript code into that loop to convert each input docx file into pdf, but i absolutely don't know how to use AppleScript.

What is the correct AppleScript syntax for following:

1. AppleScript takes docx file as an shortcuts.app action input;
2. Send it to word.app;
3. Word.app saves it as pdf file in the same folder;
4. AppleScript sends saved pdf file to the next shortcut action.

Answer (score 1):

Your task may be completed using Pages.app which is **free preinstalled application** on every Mac.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set docxFileHFS to (item 1 of input) as text -->  one hfs path
    
    tell application "System Events"
        if not (name extension of file docxFileHFS is "docx") then
            display dialog "The input is not DOCX file "
            return
        end if
    end tell
    set pdfHFS to text 1 thru -6 of (docxFileHFS) & ".pdf"
    
    tell application "Pages"
        set theDocument to open file docxFileHFS
        export theDocument to file pdfHFS as PDF
        close theDocument saving no
    end tell
    
    return pdfHFS as alias
end run
```

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to use this script with msword, if i'll application from "pages" to "microsoft word"?

Comment: No, Microsoft Word.app has different scripting dictionary.

Comment: Here is example saving the active document as PDF: **save as active document file name filname file format format PDF**. Note that Microsoft Word.app has some sandbox restrictions when accessing your hard disk directories. So, you should add also following code before, which clears all restrictions: **set sd to path to startup disk
tell application id "com.microsoft.Word"
   try
       close sd
   end try** I don't want to install this application, so can't help you further.